# Does force perpendicular to velocity change its magnitude?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, velocity

Of course there is the definition of work as a scalar product of $\vec F$ (force) and $\mathrm{d}\vec r$ (displacement). That would mean that if the force is perpendicular to the velocity of an object, it cannot change its magnitude (only the direction), no matter how big is it.
But if one goes to an inertial system where the object is stationary, one would have the same force (invariant under Galilean transformation) acting on an stationary object. According the second law, the body will move in the direction of the force with some velocity $\vec v_1$, which means perpendicular to the initial velocity $\vec v$, because $\vec F$ is perpendicular to $\vec v$. I think, when returning to the original system, subtracting $\vec v$ one will get velocity $\vec v_2=\vec v_1-\vec v$, which will not be the same $\vec v_2$ not equal to $\vec v$. Especially while $\vec F$ can be different $\vec v_1$ also is different and $\vec v=\vec v_1-\vec v$ is valid only under certain $\vec F$.
It seems a contradiction!

Comment: Your mistake is that moving to a frame where the object is stationary, you are forgetting the pseudoforces that arise due to this change of frame.

Comment: What pseudoforces do appear? I use only inertial frames!

Comment: You will perceive a new force, the centrifugal force, which is a result of moving to the frame of the particle. It's the same feeling one gets in a car making a turn. By the way, your frame isn't inertial since it is undergoing acceleration.

Comment: The body (particle) is not rotating! Just moving with constant velocity! No turns at all! Then the observer moves with the same speed. If these are not inertial frames I don't know what is an inertial frame. Where do you see acceleration? Maybe after application of the force the particle will turn but not my observation system.

Comment: @Triatticus have you read my remark? Where is accelaration in my system? The particle is moving with constant speed in system 1 and then system 2 is moving with this speed to system 1.

Comment: Just attach a set of axes to the particle in the frame of reference of the center of the circle, it's clear to see that set of axes rotates as the particle moves around the circle, thus it's an accelerated rotating frame.

Comment: @Triatticus   Sorry for the delay. No. I don't use such frame. My frame is say 1 m away from the particle and moving along with it. It is inertial and there are no fictive forces. Of course your system is non-inertial and there is no need of using it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the force is perpendicular to velocity, then, as you correctly stated, it will do no work and will not change the speed.

Note that for no work to be done for some time interval, then at every instant within that interval, the force must be perpendicular to the velocity.

Now, as for your example with a stationary object:

Suppose you apply a force upwards. Initially, the object will not move. The work will be zero, because $\delta \bf \vec r = 0$, since the force will be applied for an instant so small, [no change in velocity will occur](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217259/acceleration-constant-force-vs-force-for-an-instant).

However, if you apply that force for a finite amount of time, long enough to cause a displacement, then that force will no longer be perpendicular to the velocity.

Also, your statement

> body will move in the direction of the force with some velocity ${\bf \vec v}_1$

is wrong. The body will not move in the direction of the force. Take uniform circular motion, for example. The net force is always directed inwards, towards the center, but the object never moves to the center.

Comment: I assume you are referring to centripetal force and circular motion?

Comment: For me is confusing the question will a perpendicular force ad a perpendicular dv  to v changing so the magnitude of v.....

Comment: According to your statement that because force acts for infinite small amount of time, is it this true when the force is against the speed? Then can not each force be viewed as a sum over infinite small amount of time and then one should draw the conclusion that it does not do work at all

Comment: According to your second statement that the body does not move along the force direction notice that this is an inertial frame where the body is at rest at moment 0. The Newton second law clearly states what happens. Your example with circular motion is not appropriate. This an inertial frame and the pseudoforce compensates the real force in such systems.

Comment: Psi two you say "for an instant so small, no change in velocity will occur." The acceleration and force have no time delay in the II law. No there is a time delay in the velocity v=at. Of course in time 0 nothing happens. No matter weather the force is perpendicular or parallel.